# How to know whether a subpath is contained into another longer path in Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given a set of paths belonged to Neo4j database, I want to know which of these paths are subpaths of another longer path.

For example:

### Set of paths

1. (a)-[r]-> (b)
2. (a)-[r]-> (b)->[r]-> (c)
3. (a)-[r]-> (b)->[r]-> (c)->[r]-> (d)
4. (a)-[r]-> (d)

### The expected response would be:

1. (a)-[r]->(b)
2. (a)-[r]-> (b)->[r]-> (c)

Both paths included in longer path:
(a)-[r]-> (b)->[r]-> (c)->[r]-> (d)

Is there any syntax in Cypher to to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are actually trying to use a [variable-length path](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-match.html?textToSearch=variable+length#match-variable-length-relationships) query to get just "complete paths" (i.e., paths that end at a leaf node), without any partial paths.

If my suspicion is correct, then there may be an easy way (given your sample paths) to do that.

For example, if your current query is:

```
MATCH p=(a:Foo)-[:REL*]->(b:Bar)
RETURN p;
```

You can use the following query to just get "complete" paths:

```
MATCH p=(a:Foo)-[:REL*]->(b:Bar)
WHERE NOT (b)-[:REL]->()
RETURN p;
```